# How to set up a delay between two Vertex AI components in a pipeline?

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai, kubeflow-pipelines

I am working on a pipeline using Vertex AI, and I'm facing an issue with scheduling the execution of two components with a delay. Here's the scenario:

1. Component A generates some data as its output.
2. Component B processes
   the output from Component A and sends the result to an external
   provider for further processing. This external provider typically
   takes around 2 hours to complete its task.
3. Component C should be
   scheduled to run 2 hours after Component B has finished.

My question is, how can I set up this delay between Component B and Component C in the pipeline?

I have considered using the pipeline orchestration capabilities provided by Vertex AI, but I couldn't find a built-in feature for adding such delays between components. I also looked into using Cloud Scheduler, but it seems more suitable for triggering pipeline runs rather than introducing delays within a pipeline.

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to accomplish this delay between the execution of Component B and Component C in the Vertex AI pipeline. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Does this [link](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/pipelines/schedule-cloud-scheduler) will help you for resolving your issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend having a separate pipeline for component C. When the component B in the first pipeline completes, publish a message to PuSub and then trigger the Pipeline of Component C with that message in PubSub. For more info: https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/pipelines/trigger-pubsub

Comment: I went with a similar approach and created a different pipeline for component C and used the scheduler to run it 2 hours after the first pipeline (containing components A and B) was scheduled to run. Not the best solution, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Would a new component that does time.sleep for two hours do the job?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).