# How to Trigger a Vertex AI Component After a Previous Pipeline Component Has Failed?

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai, kubeflow-pipelines

I am working on a Vertex AI pipeline, and I have a scenario where one of my components (let's call it X) occasionally fails during pipeline execution. When component X fails, I want to trigger a specific component (Y).

There's the `kfp.dsl.Condition` option, but I'm not entirely sure how to use it for this particular scenario. Can someone provide guidance on how to set up this conditional execution of Component Y when Component X fails?
Ideally, I'd like to set up a mechanism where, upon the failure of Component X, Component Y is automatically executed to handle the failure scenario. Does Vertex Ai/Kubeflow Pipelines provide any native features or options to achieve this?

Comment: Can you follow these [features not supported in the Vertex AI Pipelines](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/pipelines/migrate-kfp#features_not_supported_in) document ?  I hope it will help you.

Comment: Can you confirm whether the above link is helpful or not ? If not then please share the error you are facing.

Comment: Hi @pajamas, If my answer addresses your question, do consider accepting and upvoting it as per Stack Overflow guidelines, helping more Stack contributors with their research. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Sim in this [stack link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76387900/how-to-set-up-a-delay-between-two-vertex-ai-components-in-a-pipeline). I'd recommend having a separate pipeline for component Y. When the component X in the first pipeline completes, publish a message to Pub/Sub and then trigger the Pipeline of Component Y with that message in Pub/Sub.

For more information you can check this [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/pipelines/trigger-pubsub). and [doc1](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/pipelines/run-pipeline).

Posting the answer as community wiki for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future. Feel free to edit this answer for additional information.